# Fb - Flo Error EBUSY hyberfil.sys

Tags: node.js, events, nodes, unhandled

I just installed Fb Flo with Nodejs , copied the documentation example in a file and ran it like this : node flo.js and i get this error :

events.js:72
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error : EBUSY , lstat 'C:hiberfil:sys'

I read on a post that it's an error that happen when node try to write an admin system but no idea why I got this. 
I'm running the terminal as admin .

Ty for your helps